# Samba tdbsam users limit

Tags: samba

I have a samba server with ldap to manage users in my office. I have been reading articles about creating a samba server and I have founded out something about users limit: "the Samba Team does not recommend using the tdbsam backend for sites that have 250 or more users.", many articles say the same about this limit, but this articles are old, some of them about 10 years old.

My question is: Is Tdbsam backend still recommend using at least 250 users? Is there another limit recomendation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to this exact question on page 85 of John H. Terpstra's guide [Samba-3 by Example](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/95-799/Samba-Guide.pdf):

> The tdb data structure and support system can handle more entries than the number of accounts that are possible on most UNIX systems. There is a practical limit that would come into play long before a performance boundary would be anticipated. [...]
>
> As the network grows, it becomes necessary to provide additional authentication servers (domain controllers). The tdbsam is limited to a single machine and cannot be reliably replicated. This means that practical limits on network design dictate the point at which a distributed passdb backend is required; at this time, there is no real alternative other than ldapsam (LDAP).
>
> The guideline provided in TOSHARG, Chapter 10, Section 10.1.2, is to limit the number of accounts in the tdbsam backend to 250. This is the point at which most networks tend to want backup domain controllers (BDCs). Samba-3 does not provide a mechanism for replicating tdbsam data so it can be used by a BDC. **The limitation of 250 users per tdbsam is predicated only on the need for replication not on the limits of the tdbsam backend itself.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: @RGPossani mark this question as answered then, please?